# I used the DOM object under my script tag in my ejs template but it is not working. how do I fix this problem?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

```
<%-include ("partials/header.ejs") %>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <header>
        <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
    <img class="calender-pic" src="images/calendar.png">
  </header>
<!--END OF NAVIGATION BAR-->
<h1> TO DO LIST WEBPAGE</h1>
           <div class="item" >
                      <ul> 
                       <% tasks.forEach(task => { %> 
                        <li class="check"> <%=task %></li>
                      <% }); %> 
                    </ul>
                      <form action="/submit" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="New Item" required/>
                      <button type="submit" >+</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName('li').addEventListener('click', check);
function check(){
  console.log(1+1);
}
                      </script>

<%-include("partials/footer.ejs")%>
```

I expect to see  >2 on my console
but I keep getting

```
 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an ARRAY.  You need to use a `for` loop to run through the array and add the event to each element.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName`, as the plural in the name implies, returns an ARRAY of elements.  You need to iterate through that array.

```
const items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for( let i = 0; i < items.length, i++ )
{
    items[i].addEventListener['click', check);
}
```